# fiware NGSI-LD orion-ld context broker didn't send all entities for a type as expected

Tags: get, entities

I filled a fiware orion-ld with ca 90.000 addresses (ID's like '`urn:ngsi-ld:address:Testtown:12345:Haus-Knipp-Str:15`').
If I read all entities for type "Address" from orion-ld broker via url (with offset settings, step by step with limit 1000) like "`http://{{orion}}/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?type=Address&offset=0&limit=1000`" I receive at any time the expected answer from orion-ld until I try to request
"`http://{{orion}}/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?type=Address&offset=25000&limit=1000`".
Then the unexpected answer is "`[]`". It should be filled with 1000 entities.

If I delete all entities for type "Address" stepwise by 1000 entities (each time I request the first 1000 entities and delete them afterward), I am able to delete >98000 entities. So all 98000 entities were in the orion-ld. But I wasn't able to read all entities from orion-ld.

I try to find out the last readable entity, it is "`http://{{orion}}/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?type=Address&offset=25248&limit=1`" the next request failed: "`http://{{orion}}/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?type=Address&offset=25249&limit=1`" If I try to get entities above the 25248 it failed at all.

If I check, if all 98000 ID's for type "Address" are in orion-ld, I request them by url "`http://{{orion}}/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/{{id}}`". I receive for each ID the expected answer. So all ID's are in the orion-ld. Only the read request failed, starting with offset>25248.

Is there an error in orion-ld, or an unknown threshold, which needs to be handled in another way?

---

Today I create 100,000 entities of type "`TestTestTest`" like:

```
{
    "@context": "https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/v1/ngsi-ld-core-context.jsonld",
    "id": "TestTestTest:20000",
    "type": "TestTestTest",
    "name": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": 20000
    }
},
```

If I try to read all entities of type "`TestTestTest`" again I found another threshold: **87637**

```
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=86000 and limit=1000 --> successfull: read 1000 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87000 and limit=1000 --> error: read 0 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87000 and limit=500 --> successfull: read 500 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87500 and limit=500 --> error: read 0 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87500 and limit=250 --> error: read 0 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87500 and limit=125 --> successfull: read 125 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87625 and limit=125 --> error: read 0 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87625 and limit=62 --> error: read 0 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87625 and limit=31 --> error: read 0 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87625 and limit=15 --> error: read 0 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87625 and limit=7 --> successfull: read 7 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87632 and limit=7 --> error: read 0 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87632 and limit=3 --> successfull: read 3 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87635 and limit=3 --> successfull: read 3 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87638 and limit=3 --> error: read 0 values
read all entities for type TestTestTest with offset=87638 and limit=1 --> error: read 0 values
try to read the last readable entity with type TestTestTest with offset=87637 and limit=1 --> id=TestTestTest:87637
try to read an entity after the last readable entity with type TestTestTest with offset=87638 and limit=1 --> []
ERROR, the requested amount of entities (iOffset=87637) seems not the expected count.
```

I use the following version of orion-ld on a docker environment:

```
{
    "orionld version": "post-v0.8.1",
    "orion version": "1.15.0-next",
    "uptime": "7 d, 12 h, 2 m, 55 s",
    "git_hash": "nogitversion",
    "compile_time": "Wed Dec 15 15:12:50 UTC 2021",
    "compiled_by": "root",
    "compiled_in": "",
    "release_date": "Wed Dec 15 15:12:50 UTC 2021",
    "doc": "https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/master/"
}
```

It would be nice if you can help in this case.
Thanks, Knigge

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this really seems to be a bug in Orion-LD.
As a bug, we need it as an issue on the github repo.
Could you file an issue .... [here](https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/issues) ?
(that way you'll be informed on updates)

Answer (score 0):

So, I filled my DB with 27000 entities and tested:

```
ldcurl GET "/entities?type=T&offset=26000&count=true&limit=1000"
```

(ldcurl is a tiny script of mine that adds host, port, accept-header etc)

I had no problem, got this output for the sample test with offset 26000

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 138003
Content-Type: application/json
Link: <https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/v1/ngsi-ld-core-context.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/json-ld#context"; type="application/ld+json"
NGSILD-Results-Count: 27000
Date: Thu, 27 Jan 2022 19:31:14 GMT


[
  {
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:entities:E26001",
    "type": "T",
    "A1": {
      "type": "Property",
      "value": "E26002:A1"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:entities:E26002",
    "type": "T",
    "A1": {
      "type": "Property",
      "value": "E26003:A1"
    }
  },
  ...
```

I tested with what's currently in the **develop** branch and also with what's in **release/1.0.0**.

Look me up on skype, same user name as here in SOF, perhaps we can look at your problem together, as I don't seem to be able to reproduce it myself.

Meanwhile, I'll make my entities more similar to yours, see if I have more luck that way.